# ZUUL send basic authentication to downstream application

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a spring boot microservice which requires basic authentication data ie fixed userid/password (like admin/password). I am using Spring cloud netflix ecosystem to orchestrate microservices. **Zuul** is my API gateway.

My question how to send basic authentication details to my application from Zuul so that when accessed via Zuul it won't ask for userid/password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom filter and add the Authorization header to the request.
The Authorization header is simply base64 encoded "username:password" string.

```
public class AuthenticatedFilter extends ZuulFilter {

  @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 10;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    String auth = "username" + ":" + "password";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
    String authValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authValue);        
    return null;
  }
}
```

EDIT: You'll also need to create the bean for this filter for Zuul to pick it up. So in your Configuration class/Main application class, add:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticatedFilter getAuthenticatedFilter () {
    return new AuthenticatedFilter();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that but how to send userid and password as part of the Authorization header?

Comment: I updated my answer.
I short, for generating the userid and password part of the header, simply base64 encode the "username:password" string.

Comment: You could also use StandardCharsets